# How to use within() function with contains() function incypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have a datepicker calendar as below [![enter image description here][1]][1]
To select a particular date I am using this code

```
cy.get('.fa-calendar').click();
cy.get('[label="select-year"]').select(2023);
cy.get('[label="select-month"]').select('Jan');
```

Now to select the date I am using below approach which is working fine

```
cy.get('.ngb-dp-month>ng-star-inserted:nth-of-type(1)').within(()=>{
cy.get('.ngb-dp-day').contains('10').click();
})
```

but I don't wanted to use `nth-of-type(1)` because it will cause issue in future I tried this approach whic didn't work

```
cy.contains('January 2023').within(()=>{
    cy.get('.ngb-dp-day').contains('10').click();
    });
```

Can you folks help me resolving the issue also any other alternative is also welcome
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38XyO.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you just need to combine the two different ways you tried: `cy.get('.ngb-dp-month')` and `cy.contains('January 2023')`

This should work

```js
cy.contains('.ngb-dp-month', 'January 2023').within(()=> {
  cy.contains('.ngb-dp-day', '10')
    .click()
})
```